# Error inserting ISO8601 string literal into Azure SQL DB datetimeoffset column using pyodbc

Tags: azure-sql-database, pyodbc, iso8601

I am trying (actually failing) to insert a string literal ISO 8601 `timestamp`, using pyodbc, into an Azure SQL db table column of type `datetimeoffset(3).`

```
cursor.execute(
    'INSERT INTO AP_TEST (Id, t_zulu) VALUES (?, ?)',
    '1234',
    '2017-08-04T17:03:37.266Z'
)
```

Here's the exception:

> pyodbc.DataError: ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (241) (SQLExecDirectW)')

What am I missing here?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server takes a different format for `datetimeoffset`, AFAIK. Try:

```
'2017-09-20 20:32:10 +10:0'
```

See the docs and examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql

Good luck!